# d3js zoom svg and axix

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, babeljs

I'm trying to draw an  external svg file into a webpage using d3 and make it zoom on scroll.
I followed http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892919 but when i add my svg file it remain fixed and doesn't zoom.
I will draw several svg so i will have an array like this:

```
var data = []
data.push({
  name: "base",
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  width: 350,
  url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Svg.svg'
});
```

and draw it with a function:

```
function add(elements, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0) {
  for (let e of elements) {
    d3.xml(e.url, 'image/svg+xml', function(error, xml) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('error' + error)
        throw error;
      }
      var svgNode = xml.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
      d3.select(svgNode).attr('id', e.name)
        .attr('x', e.x + offsetX)
        .attr('y', e.y + offsetY);
      svg.node().appendChild(svgNode);
      svg.select('#' + e.name)
        .attr('width', e.width);
    });
  }
}
```

full [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ny299ge/3/)

Comment: looks like you're not appending the circles to the correct element. Which means the zoom wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked around the pan & zoom examples available and this is what I found.
In the `zoomed` function, there should be a translate and scale on the elements appended, not just the x and y axis.

So, I created a group where to append the elements:

```
var elementsToScale = svg.append("g").attr("id", "elementsToScale")
```

And I added the last lines in the `zoomed` function:

```
function zoomed() {
  svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
  var translate = d3.event ? d3.event.translate : "0,0"
  var scale = d3.event ? d3.event.scale : "1"
  svg.select("#elementsToScale").attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")" + " scale(" + scale + ")");    
}
```

And then I changed the `add` function to append the elements to the `elementsToScaleGroup`:

```
d3.xml(el.url, 'image/svg+xml', function(error, xml) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('error' + error)
      throw error;
    }
    var svgNode = xml.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    d3.select(svgNode).attr('id', e.name)
      .attr('x', el.x + offsetX)
      .attr('y', el.y + offsetY);

    elementsToScale.node().appendChild(svgNode);
    elementsToScale.select('#' + el.name)
      .attr('width', el.width);
});
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/84d0L6v4/).

The only thing left is the tween on the elements appended on reset.